# How to edit checkbox using explode

Tags: php, html, mysql

I hope that stackoverflow members can help me with my problem. I am new in implode function in php so I am quite confuse about its whole function.
I have multiple checkbox for skills like java,php,css, asp,vb,mysql and etc.
I tried to save them in a single column in the database using implode.

```
$skills = implode(',',$skills);
<input type="checkbox" name="skills[0]" value="java">java
<input type="checkbox" name="skills[1]" value="php">php
<input type="checkbox" name="skills[2]" value="css">css
<input type="checkbox" name="skills[3]" value="asp">asp
```

for update:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="skills[0]" value='<?php $skills=explode(',',$skills);?>
<?php if     ($skills[0] = "java"){?>  checked="checked" <?php }?>'>

<input type="checkbox" name="skills[1]" value='<?php $skills=explode(',',$skills);?>
<?php if     ($skills[1] = "php"){?>  checked="checked" <?php }?>'>

<input type="checkbox" name="skills[2]" value='<?php $skills=explode(',',$skills);?>
<?php if     ($skills[2] = "css"){?>  checked="checked" <?php }?>'>

<input type="checkbox" name="skills[3]" value='<?php $skills=explode(',',$skills);?>
<?php if     ($skills[3] = "asp"){?>  checked="checked" <?php }?>'>
```

My code for update does not work because if I update the checkbox, there are checkboxes that is unchecked supposedly but it is checked when I tried to edit it.
Then base on the comment, unchecked checkbox will not saved in the database which is true. I tried to read some related problems here but I think mine is different, if not please provide.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: If the checkbox is uncheked - it doesn't exists in `$_POST`. Also `$skills[0] = "asp"` is wrong statement, as it's a assigment and not a comparison

Comment: any idea how to save the checkbox in a single column in the database and update in the future so that when i edit my checkbox skills, the checked checkbox is still checked and the unchecked checkbox is still unchecked? sorry im just new in this kind of problem in checkbox using php.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

```
<?php
        $skills=explode(',',$skills); 
        if(in_array('java', $skills))
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="skills[0]" value="java" checked>java';
        else
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="skills[0]" value="java">java';
        if(in_array('php', $skills))
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="skills[1]" value="php" checked>php';
        else
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="skills[1]" value="php">php';

        if(in_array('css', $skills))
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="skills[2]" value="css" checked>css';
        else
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="skills[2]" value="css">css';

        if(in_array('asp', $skills))
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="skills[3]" value="asp" checked>asp';
        else
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="skills[3]" value="asp">asp';
    ?>
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, it throws an error: 
Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Comment: is there any possible way that if the checkbox is not checked then null or 0 will be saved in the database??

Comment: if $skills variable value is: $skills="java,css,php" then you use this code, because in question there was implode function is used.

Answer (score 1):

Below Answer is right but i check one addition condition

```
if (empty($skills))
        {
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="skills[0]" value="java">java';
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="skills[1]" value="php">php';
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="skills[2]" value="css">css';
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="skills[3]" value="asp">asp';         
        }
else
        {
             $skills=explode(',',$skills); 
            if(in_array('java', $skills))
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="skills[0]" value="java" checked>java';
            else
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="skills[0]" value="java">java';
            if(in_array('php', $skills))
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="skills[1]" value="php" checked>php';
            else
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="skills[1]" value="php">php';

            if(in_array('css', $skills))
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="skills[2]" value="css" checked>css';
            else
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="skills[2]" value="css">css';

            if(in_array('asp', $skills))
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="skills[3]" value="asp" checked>asp';
            else
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="skills[3]" value="asp">asp';

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can use "echo", not need long script

```
if(in_array('java', $skills))
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="skills[0]" value="java" {echo 'checked';}>java';
```